# Python lxml xpath с пропущенным тегом <ul>

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, lxml

Добрый день!

С помощью библиотеки lxml (python) требуется получить `content.xpath('//li[@class="list"]')`. Сейчас xpath возвращает пустой список. Полагаю, что из-за того, что отсутствует тег `<ul>` для списка `<li>`.

Как красиво и просто получить набор данных  `content.xpath('//li[@class="list"]')` для конкретного примера?

```
<div class="aaa">
<li class="list">aaaa</li>
<li class="list">bbbb</li>
<li class="list">cccc</li>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня `content.xpath('//li[@class="list"]')` отлично работает и возвращает все три указанных элемента. Не могли бы вы дать [минимльный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), который я без изменений скормил бы питону и в итоге получил бы вашу проблему?

Comment: Я пытаюсь вытащить данные с  [ссылка](https://www.myhome.ge/ka/search?geo_search=on&scroll_top=0&pr_grid_id=1) . Не получается достучаться до li элементов их содержимого `root = content.xpath('//div[@class="pr relative pr_search"]//li')` xpath просто не видит конкретные  li элементы

Comment: Вытащил xml кусок начиная с `//div[@class="pr relative pr_search"]` и присвоил его строковой переменной. В этом случае `html.fromstring + xpath` работает корректно и xpath находит все li элементы, но на самой исходной странице, та же конструкция не находит те же самые `li` элементы.

Comment: Есть понимание что проблема в самой странице и что там что-то не так с тегами. Но как найти причину и как ее обойти ?

Comment: Вот так выглядит содержимое xpath `html.tostring() = <div class="pr relative pr_search" id="search_pr">\n                                            </div>\n`. то есть `li` элементы отуствуют.

Comment: даже ухищрения не особо помогли. `        s = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html5lib')
        s.prettify()     
        response = str(s)
        content = html.fromstring(response)

        records = {}
        rule_config = self.rules[rule]
        root = content.xpath(rule_config['root'])
        try:
            t = html.tostring(root[0],method='html')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        print(t)`

Comment: Элементов li на странице и нет, они на ходу генерируются джаваскриптом уже после загрузки страницы. Перехватывайте трафик инструментами разработчика и смотрите, каким запросом скачиваются нужные вам данные. Подсказка: ни lxml, ни beautifulsoup здесь вообще нафиг не нужны.

Comment: еще одну подсказку если можно. о каком инструменте идет речь ? я использую chrome developer tools.  мне нужно все привести к формату понятному lxml, поскольку учу python и хочу написать собственный  движок для парсинга страниц. правила для парсинга у меня хранятся виде путей для xpath

Comment: О вкладке network в этом вашем developer tools. Если вы внимательно посмотрите данные, которые там передаются, то не увидите никаких li, а увидите вполне себе json)

Comment: для случая если я хочу работать через xpath, самое оптимальное использовать библиотеку selenium чтобы прогружать и выполнять страницу как это делает браузер? или есть еще более оптимальный вариант?

Comment: PhantomJS ещё есть